# Cannot append value to list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, inheritance

I am creating a custom class `mylist` that inherits from `list` in python.

But I am unable to append values

```py
class mylist(list):

    def __init__(self,max_length):
        super().__init__()
        self.max_length = max_length        

    def append(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Append object to the end of the list. """
        if len(self) > self.max_length:
            raise Exception

a = mylist(5)
a.append(5)
print(a)

# output
#[]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I needed to inherit builtin 'list' datatype in python and create a custom list with max_length attribute

Comment: You need to _write_ the implementation; the purpose of setting the exercise is so that you think and learn, not copy. How do you inherit from an existing class? Override an inherited method? Which methods on a list change the length?

Comment: Yeah.  I have tried on my own

class mylist(list):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.max_length = 0

    def append(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Append object to the end of the list. """
        if len() > self.max_length:
            raise Exception


I am struck after this

Comment: What do you mean "struck" - what's the _specific problem_ with your implementation? Give a [mre].

Comment: How can I check whether my list has reached max_length?. What should I put inside  len() on append method

Comment: Well what _is_ the list you want the length of? How do you normally refer to the current instance in a method?

Comment: we usually refer using "self" keyword inside the class. Please correct me If I am wrong

Comment: Hi I have updated the questions

Comment: In your `append` method, you change `max_length` (this probably should not happen, if adding items changes the maximum number of items what's the point of it?) but don't do anything with the value (`args[0]`) the caller tried to add. So what did you expect? In general I think the task is under-specified - what should happen if the max_length is set to less than the current length? What should happen if the user tries to extend the list with multiple items, only some of which will fit?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the code. We can consider the list to be empty and max_length will be set while creating the object. So max_length will be greater than current length. 2) when extends occurs we need to fill upto max_length

By the way the question is reopened

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237829/discussion-between-jebaseelan-ravi-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined own `append()` so you replaced original `append()` and it doesn't add element to list.

You could use `super()` to run original `append()`

```
    def append(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Append object to the end of the list. """
        if len(self) > self.max_length:
            raise Exception

        if args:
            super().append(args[0])
```

I think you should use `>=` instead of `>` because you check it before adding item. You could use `>` if you would check it after adding item

---

**BTW:**

Because you use `*args` so you can use `for`-loop to append may values `a.append(5, 6, 7)`. Original `append()` can't do this.

```
        for item in args:        
            super().append(item)
```

It may need to check if `len(self) + len(args) > self.max_length` or it may need to check `len(self)` inside `for`-loop

You could also check if `args` has any value and raise error when you run `a.append()` without any value.

---

```
class MyList(list):  # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames` for classes

    def __init__(self, max_length):
        super().__init__()
        self.max_length = max_length        

    def append(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Append object to the end of the list. """
        #if len(self) >= self.max_length:
        #    raise Exception
        
        #if args:
        #    super().append(args[0])

        if not args: # use `TypeError` like in `list.append()`
            raise TypeError("descriptor 'append' of 'list' object needs an argument")

        for item in args:
            if len(self) >= self.max_length:
                 raise Exception
            super().append(item)

    def insert(self, pos, value):
        if len(self) >= self.max_length:
            raise Exception
        super().insert(pos, value)

# --- main ---

#list.append()  # raise `TypeError`
            
a = MyList(5)

try:
    a.append()  # raise `TypeError` like in `list.append()`
except Exception as ex:
    print('ex:', ex)

a.append(5)
print(a)      # [5]

a.append(6, 7, 8, 9)
print(a)      # [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

a.append(10)  # raise ERROR

a.insert(0, 999)  # raise ERROR
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful. I have overrided extends method for appending multiple values

Comment: I added some modifications in full example.

Comment: BTW: if you want append many elements then you can use standard `a.extend( [5,6,7] )` or shorter `a += [5,6,7]` - so you don't have to define own class.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to check if I have exceed max_length. if the user tries to extend the list with multiple items, only some of which will fit?. for example if the max_length is 5 and current length is 4 and user tries to extends 5 elements only one should fill

Comment: in new version I check `len(self)` inside `for`-loop so it raise error but it add values which fit to `max_length`. I f you do `a.append(1,2,3,4,5,6)` (and you catch error) then you get `[1,2,3,4,5]` without `6`. You should also write own `extend()` and `insert()` to check `max_length`

Comment: I have written extend. Can you please help with ```insert``` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237859/discussion-between-furas-and-jebaseelan-ravi).